# How to redefine a function at runtime, without restarting the program?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a code like this:

```
def draw():
    Display.render_text(color="white", align="left", text="This is a text")

while True:
    draw()
```

And suddenly I want to edit `draw()` to something like:

```
def draw():
    Display.render_text(color="green", align="center", text="THIS CHANGES EVERYTHING!")
```

How do I do this without restarting the whole program? When I'm in the python's interactive console, I just edit `draw()` a bit, copypaste it into console, and then copypaste `while True:` loop. But I don't know how to do something like that with a programs which are started from the shell.

So, I need to somehow tell python to pause execution as soon as he leaves the `draw()` function, quickly swap it with a new version, and continue the execution.

I suspect that Common Lisp can do something like that, it has really good debugging features. C# can do this, but you have to manually pause your program before editing anything, which I'm too lazy to do (I need to teach Visual Studio to automatically pause execution at the right time, hotkey for recompilation, etc). C can do this with hotpatching, but I'm yet to meet a working example of that. Go probably can do something like this if you disable some of it's optimisations, like inlining and maybe some others, in a way simular to C. Lua was created for this. Python probably can do this, but I don't know how.

Comment: Why not simply alter the variables that are passed in, instead of wanting to replace the whole function definition?! You know... *variables* can... *vary*. That's what they're for.

Comment: @deceze but then I'll still have to stop the thole program just to add those variables, I'll still have to edit code.

Comment: you can take a look at `reload`. listen to keyboard event, and do reload is a specified key is pressed

Comment: In practice, what exactly are you talking about? When/how/where would these changes happen exactly anyway? Let's put it this way: plenty of Python programs have been written which redraw the UI without dynamically replacing functions at runtime. - Talking about *hot code swapping* is an interesting topic in itself, but I really kinda doubt that's what's necessary here.

Comment: Well, I'm thinking about a text editor written in python, which can edit it's own source code, and apply changes without restarting. Kind of like emacs does, if he indeed works like that. Thank you for the term, google showed me a lot of interesting stuff.

Comment: I don't think this can be done in a sane manner because even if you hotswap functions and types there are still values created from former code which don't magically change their behaviour which leads to behaviour which isn't reproducable by restarting the program. You can get a little closer by not changing functions and types but just the code of functions and methods.  But this can't be done without assumptions about the Python runtime that is implementation specific.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

exec("def pt():\n    print('two')")

Comment: What? Have something to say?

Answer (score 0):

Something that might come close to what you want is some kind of "function factory", which creates functions according to parameters you specify:

```
def factory(param1,param2,...):
    def result():
        Display.render_text(color=param1, align="left", text=param2)
        # do other magical things depending on the parameters
    return result

f = factory('green','Hallo')
f()
f = factory('white','Test')
f()
```

Comment: No, that's not it. Code my original post is just an example, and what I want is exactly what I said I want: to redefine a function. Also, your code doesn't work inside an infinite loop, this is an important requirement.

Comment: Depending on how sophisticated your factory is you can get quite some flexibility in creating and redefining your function f depending on the parameters you specify. What I proposed was as well simply meant as an example. But yes, this solution is not as flexible as redefining the source code for your function. What you apparently need is to let the Python interpreter execute a string, which could be done with the "exec" statement. Anyway, not a nice solution...